# Symfony 3.4: How to get serviceContainer in UnitTest

Tags: php, visual-studio, unit-testing, symfony, logging

I want to access the object of my class import

but I passed LoggerInterface $logger in its container:

```
class Import
{
....
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
     ...
    }

....
 }
```

so when I accessed this object in my testimport class

```
class ImportTest extends TestCase {
....
   protected function setUp()
    {
      $this->ImportObj = new Import(); // I have to pass some 
                                       // object as an object is passed 
                                       // in import class   
    ....   
    }
....
}
```

And as we know instead of new Import() we can use serviceContainer logic to achieve this

```
$this->ImportObj=$this->getContainer()->get('\Import');
```

**But i cant't access this service container outside my bundle , so my question is how i can make it workable.**

Comment: you can also provide mock logger object to `new Import();`